# Following Rails Tutorial and a syntax error is stopping a test passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest, railstutorial.org

Unfortunately I am receiving a syntax error that is hiding for me. Could anyone help? I understand it is relevant to the method 'assert_select' for the divs, but I am not sure why it is not passing.

My error:

```
Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '#' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x0055b3736715e8 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["div"]>]'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

My test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    test "invalid signup information" do
        get signup_path
        assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
            post users_path, params: { user: {
                name: "",
                email: "user@invalid",
                password: "foo",
                password_confirmation: "bar"
                }}
            end
            assert_template 'users/new'
            assert_select 'div#<CSS id for error explanation>'
            assert_select 'div.<CSS class for field with error>'
    end
```

Code it is testing. Users/new:

```
<% provide(:title, "sign up") %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
            <%= f. password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>

            <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

            <% end %>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Shared/_error_messages:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
        </div>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are following the Hartl rails tutorial so you copy and pasted the information or forgot to fill in the info.

On line 15, you have `'div#<CSS id for error explanation>'` It should instead be the CSS for error explanation... `'div#error_explanation'` and the following `'div.field_with_errors'`

Answer (score 0):

in assert_select you asked it to go to 'div' in css 
so you need just to write its name